# Lumen (Laravel) crear un fichero de helpers personalizado

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, lumen

He creado un fichero en la ruta `app/Helpers/helper.php` donde quiero incluir los helpers que necesito para mi proyecto en lumen, de momento tengo este código

```
<?php

namespace App\Helpers;
/**
 * Generate a  "random" alpha-numeric string.
 *
 * @param  int  $length
 * @return string
 *
 * @throws \RuntimeException
 */


function randomStr($length = 60)
{
  if (!function_exists('openssl_random_pseudo_bytes')) {
    throw new RuntimeException('OpenSSL extension is required.');
  }

  $bytes = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($length * 2);

  if ($bytes === false) {
    throw new RuntimeException('Unable to generate random string.');
  }

  return substr(str_replace(array('/', '+', '='), '', base64_encode($bytes)), 0, $length);
}
```

En el fichero composer.json he añadido la siguiente clave

```
    "files": [
    "app/Helpers/Helper.php"
],
```

Y para hacer la llamada a la función lo hago desde un controlador de esta forma

```
$token = \App\Helpers\randomStr(30);
```

Y el error que recibo es

> Call to undefined function App\Helpers\randomStr()

Comment: Intenta luego de hacer los cambios en el composer ejecutar composer dump-autoload

Comment: @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas ya lo he probado y no hace nada , gracias

Answer (score 0):

En el archivo .json ya estás indicando la ruta del helper, ya no es necesario hacer eso en el controlador.

Trata con algo asi:

```
$token = randomStr(30);
```